# Type 'Type' already defines a member called 'Equals' with the same parameter types on Equals(object)

Tags: c#, oop, c#-9.0

I'm working on a low level class with, amoung other things, custom equality and comparison implementations.

I'm getting the follwoing error:

```
bool SystemPath.Equals(object obj)
Type 'SystemPath' already defines a member called 'Equals' with the same parameter types
```

the class in question looks like this (minumum reproduction):

```cs
public record FilePath : IEquatable<FilePath>
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Equality comparison based on path alone, not updated date
        /// </summary>
        public bool Equals(FilePath other)
//!                 ^^^^^^ Type 'FilePath' already defines a member called 'Equals' with the same parameter types
        {
            // implementation here
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Other questions on this error seem to invovle partial classes or controllers with get/post methods to the same uri. But my proplem wasn't for any method, it was specifically `Equals(TClass)`. Other method definitions and overrides work without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that my class was defined as a `record` instead of a class. since a record implicitly implements `IEquitable<TRecord>`, defining that method myself causes the error with no obvious source.

Changing the object kind from record to class solves this problem.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record